# What does this LogCat means?: E/TextView: Saved cursor position 2/2 out of range for (restored) text

Tags: android, android-layout

After set textview's color at its property, this prompt appears at logcat when run,
what does it mean?

when restore the textview color to its default, the error disappear and all is running well.

what's matter? how shall I set color of the textview correctly?
Thanks,

```
11-11 00:45:56.302: E/TextView(2828): Saved cursor position 2/2 out of range for (restored) text
```

I forget what I changed in the prog and a prompt in logcat shows like this,

```
enter code here
11-11 01:40:48.102: E/AndroidRuntime(2921): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File #ff0000 from drawable resource ID #0x7f050018: .xml extension required
11-11 01:40:48.102: E/AndroidRuntime(2921):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2255)
11-11 01:40:48.102: E/AndroidRuntime(2921):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:342)
11-11 01:40:48.102: E/AndroidRuntime(2921):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:956)
11-11 01:40:48.102: E/AndroidRuntime(2921):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:614)
11-11 01:40:48.102: E/AndroidRuntime(2921):     ... 27 more
11-11 01:40:53.693: I/Process(2921): Sending signal. PID: 2921 SIG: 9
```

In the layout, I set

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ...
    android:textColor="@string/TColor" />
```

In the string.xml,

```
<string name="TColor">#ff0000</string>
```

Comment: show us the LogCat message

Comment: E/TextView(2828): Saved cursor position 2/2 out of range for (restored) text;  and yet what means (2828)?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the whole LogCat. Not just that one line.

Comment: Yes, I can, the whole messages are all this statement repeating, about 3lines. all is in red color display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store #ff0000 as a color not a string.

Put the color in your colors.xml file in the res/values folder of your project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="my_color>#ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

Then in your text view use:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ...
    android:textColor="@color/my_color" />
```

**`<Additional>`**
Reading your last comment, I think I see where you are confused.
Yes you can put different resource types all together in one XML file. But they must still be declared as their correct types. For example this first XML below is fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="t_color">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="t_color_alternate">#dd0011</color>
    <string name="text_1">First Text</string>
    <string name="text_2">Second Text</string>
    <color name="another_color">#ee3311</color>
    <dimen name="my_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <string name="text_3">Third Text</string>

</resources>
```

This second XML however will cause you problems when you try to use the resources because the types are incorrect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="t_color">16dp</color>
    <color name="t_color_alternate">Fred</color>
    <color name="another_color">Rectangle</color>
    <dimen name="my_margin">Blue</dimen>

</resources>
```

**`<Second Additional>`**

When you declare `<string name="TColor">#ff0000</string>` the compiler will create a String object and fill it with the characters "#ff0000" when you run your app.

In other words, it is like writing **`String TColor = "#ff0000"`** in code.

Simillarly, when you declare `<color name="TColor">#ff0000</color>` the compiler will create a Color object and fill it with the color #ff0000 when you run your app.

This is like writing **`Color TColor = 0xff0000`** in code.

If you read the Reference Documentation for Strings you will see it represents a sequence of characters. A Color on the other hand represents a sequence of integers.

Finally if you read the [Reference Documentation for `TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) you will see that the XML attribute `android:textColor` is equivalent to the method `setTextColor(int)`. So when you write `<string name="TColor">#ff0000</string>` you are trying to put a String into `setTextColor(int)`.

Comment: Thank you. I was told that the color set can also be in string.xml, as above I listed. and can do in drawable. etc. now, what different from them?

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. the second file indeed will cause trouble, either from name or from value. It seems what I make a mistake is at property invoke? I have to use Color, instead of string in this color property?

Comment: however I think I declare the value at string.xml like this, <string name="TColor">#ff0000</string>, why does the sytem not find its way to the value? do I have to change anything in window-preference items?

Comment: I have thought all that in .xml is only a lable or a mark which can convey to other content by its value. Thus, #ffoooo will be filled. some doc says also like that. so do in drawable. such as @drawable/tcolor etc. I willl change to word color instead.

Comment: I use IE8 to access to this web site, it often shows a mistake appearance. and can not make a comment. odd enough.

Comment: I hope I have helped you. I see you have asked some other questions on this website, but you have not marked any of the answers as accepted. Do you realize you will get 2 reputation points every time you accept an answer? When you increase your reputation points you will get more [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) on this website. I have up-voted your question because you provided more LogCat information.

Comment: Your answer is very well, I ignored the word "string". I should change "color" instead. reply your question. I try to mark it as accepted as well as add vote, but I was alway warning that you can not do that? this make me confuse. I dont know how to use this forum either.

Comment: And the other question I have asked do really haven't yet solved. you can check up. Im a man of my word. thank you very much for your mention.      I see the vote now. thank you for your vote. and I find I also succeed to vote you once.